# Adding data to database in django issue

Tags: django

I have code like this:

```
form = TestForm(request.POST)
form.save(commit=False).save()
```

This code sometimes work sometimes dont. Problem is in auto increment id.
When i have some data in db that is not written by django and i want to add data from django i get `IntegrityError id already exists`.

I i have 2 rows in db(not added by django) i need to click "add data" 3 times. After third time when id increment to 3 all is ok.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is your table created by django or some other project?

Does the id field have auto increment set?

Comment: I do syncdb to create empty tables. After that i go to db client and add data manually.. Django confuses after that

Comment: Why are you doing the commit=False and then calling save immediately? That's just the same as calling `form.save()` without the commit=False.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you'r right...

Answer (score 0):

These integrity errors appear, when your table sequence is not updated after new item is created. Or if sequence is out of sync with reality. For example - you import items from some source and the items also contain id, which is higher than your table index sequence indicates. I have not seen a case where django messes sequences up.

So what i guess happens is, that the other source that inserts data into your database, also inserts id's and sequence is not updated. Fix that and your problems should disappear.

Comment: I also explained that. You either need that foreign source to stop inserting ID's to database so the auto increment could do its work. Or update sequences programmatically after each insert. You can alter sequences with sql.